# How do I list the AWS S3 storage classes in a single bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I looked at the AWS Console and I don't see a way to display or list the storage class in a bucket for directories. I can see how to change the storage class, but it doesn't display what it is currently set at. Is there a way to do this through the AWS Console? Can this be also be done through the AWS cli?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `list-objects` command to see the storage classes for objects in a specific bucket:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket name>
```

will give you an output similar to this for each object in the bucket:

> ```
>    {
>         "Key": "kenland-logs2019-12-24-11-20-28-5FC9DBFAA3DC7CB6",
>         "LastModified": "2019-12-24T11:20:29.000Z",
>         "ETag": "<Redacted>",
>         "Size": 662,
>         "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
>         "Owner": {
>             "DisplayName": "s3-log-service",
>             "ID": "<Redacted>"
>         }
>     },
> ```

If you only want the Key and the Storage class you can tack this on to the end:

```
--query 'Contents[].{Key: Key, StorageClass: StorageClass}'
```

**Reference**

[List Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html)

Comment: You can now do this by using S3 Inventory: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html